# Selecting only Distinct() elements

Tags: linq-to-xml

I want to distinct only the uniqe elements from the query. I have:

```
public string GetOutline(int indentLevel, XElement element)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    result = result.AppendLine(new string('-', indentLevel * 2) + element.Name);

    foreach (var childElement in element.Elements().OfType<XElement>().Select(x => x.Element).Distinct()) 
    {
        result.Append(GetOutline(indentLevel + 3, childElement));
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error like this:

> Error  2   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  C:\Users\Piotrek\Desktop\INZYNIERIA_OPROGRAMOWANIA\TK\LABORKI_I\XMLe\XMLe\Form1.cs  27  42  XMLe

Comment: see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/ec03b165-49b4-400b-b71d-6b56dfdc3bce

Comment: What does the "distinct" mean? Tell us the uniqeness criterion otherwise they all are probably different as they have different references. `element.Elements()` already returns only XElements so `OfType<XElement>()` is not needed. `Select(x => x.Element)` is incorrect (and this is why the compiler is complaining) since x `XElement` and `XElement` does not have the `.Element` property.

Comment: Can you show us sample XML plus which elements you'd like to select?